# Using the correct way to draw on a picturebox messes up the output

Tags: c#, .net, graphics

Im using a picturebox as a preview.  When I was doing it incorrectly, the picturebox matched the printed output.  When I changed it to use a bitmap, it looks poorly.  I checked the DpiX and DpiY of the graphics object and it is 96 for all of them.  The issue can be demonstrated with the following code.  Create a form with a button and picturebox.  Click the button.  Then uncomment the line "//Correctway = true;" and observe the difference.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private bool Correctway;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.Click += Button1_Click;
    }


    private void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintPageEventArgs eOutput;
        Graphics g;
        string OutputText;
        Font PrintFont;
        Bitmap Output;



        //Correctway = true;
        OutputText = "CERTIFICATION";
        PrintFont = new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Regular);
        Output = new Bitmap(850, 1100);
        if (Correctway)
            g = Graphics.FromImage(Output);
        else
            g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        eOutput = new PrintPageEventArgs(g, new Rectangle(new Point(25, 25), new Size(new Point(825, 1075))), new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(new Point(850, 1100))), new PageSettings());
        eOutput.Graphics.DrawString(OutputText, PrintFont, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
        eOutput.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray, 20, 30, Output.Width - 100, Output.Height - 130);
        if (Correctway)
            pictureBox1.Image = Output;

    }

}
```

"Poor" output.  I wish I could describe it better, but I can't figure out what is happening.
[image: This is the poor output]

This is the desired output, the output that is the result of printing and the screen output when I was using the incorrect procedure of creating a graphics object from the picturebox.
[image: This is the desired output]
Note: I tried "You can also press CTRL+G to insert an image." but it does not work.  With or without the image on the clipboard.

Comment: Define 'poorly' or show. SizeMode of Pbox? I doubt that creating PrintPageEventArgs is ever the 'correct' way..

Comment: @TaW SizeMode is Normal.  Please note: this is a sample taken from a huge codebase.  PrintPageEventArgs is required for numerous functions in the printed report.  This is merely example code to illustrate the problem, not a recommended coding solution.  Sometimes code can look or even be strange when reduced to a format appropriate for a Stackoverflow question.

Comment: _I wish I could describe it better_ So would we. Do you mean the string? It seems to have a quite poor resolution. I'll try to look into it later..

Comment: LOL, yes I agree, the quality is poor.  I did, however, check the DpiX and DpiY which were the same in both objects, 96.  I also checked the HorizontalResolution and VerticalResolution of the bitmap, which is 96 on both counts.

Comment: The __'correct' way is recommended and will work fine__ if you tune the Graphics properties. Try `g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;  g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;`  There are other options for the TextRenderingHint  and maybe TextContrast will also help - Note that the correct way to 'create' pretty much any event parameter is to __leave it to the system__. In the printpage event you still can tweak the properties..

Comment: @Taw, the TextRenderingHint did the trick.  I'm not sure if you don't understand sample code or you don't understand event arguments.  Sample code is used to demonstrate an issue and may or may not reflect the actual production code.  It only needs to address the issue.  Trying to resolve an artifact from the sample is quite pointless.  If you are having trouble using event arguments post a question, I can help you.  For example, if you are having problems with PrintEventArgs you can get that from BeginPrint; PrintPageEventArgs from PrintPage, ect.

Comment: Samplecode should not be misleading or show bad practice. - ((Note: I do not have any problems and didn't have to post a question in a very long time..)) -  Anyway, I am glad I could help you..

Answer (score 0):

Taw found the answer in his comments.  I am publishing it here to complete this post.  The solution was to use *g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;*

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private bool Correctway;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.Click += Button1_Click;
    }


    private void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintPageEventArgs eOutput;
        Graphics g;
        string OutputText;
        Font PrintFont;
        Bitmap Output;



        //Correctway = true;
        OutputText = "CERTIFICATION";
        PrintFont = new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Regular);
        Output = new Bitmap(850, 1100);
        if (Correctway)
            g = Graphics.FromImage(Output);
        else
            g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        eOutput = new PrintPageEventArgs(g, new Rectangle(new Point(25, 25), new Size(new Point(825, 1075))), new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(new Point(850, 1100))), new PageSettings());
        eOutput.Graphics.DrawString(OutputText, PrintFont, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
        eOutput.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray, 20, 30, Output.Width - 100, Output.Height - 130);
        if (Correctway)
            pictureBox1.Image = Output;

    }

}
```